# nested form components angular2 error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angular, components

I am trying to create a form with nested form sub/child components

I am following this tutorial
https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2
https://plnkr.co/edit/clTbNP7MHBbBbrUp20vr?p=info

This is how i modified it. I don't want an array. I am only after single form group/controls. 
https://plnkr.co/edit/xXXQwGMaos3yDeyF6YYy?p=preview

However I get this error. how can I fix it?

```
VM2737 core.umd.js:3004 EXCEPTION: Error in https://run.plnkr.co/8GpCKDyop2isKZyM/app/address.component.html:0:5 caused by: this.form._updateTreeValidity is not a functionErrorHandler.handleError @ VM2737 core.umd.js:3004(anonymous function) @ VM2737 core.umd.js:6592ZoneDelegate.invoke @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:192onInvoke @ VM2737 core.umd.js:6206ZoneDelegate.invoke @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:191Zone.run @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:85(anonymous function) @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:451ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:225onInvokeTask @ VM2737 core.umd.js:6197ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:224Zone.runTask @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:125drainMicroTaskQueue @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:357ZoneTask.invoke @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:297
VM2737 core.umd.js:3006 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: this.form._updateTreeValidity is not a functionErrorHandler.handleError @ VM2737 core.umd.js:3006(anonymous function) @ VM2737 core.umd.js:6592ZoneDelegate.invoke @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:192onInvoke @ VM2737 core.umd.js:6206ZoneDelegate.invoke @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:191Zone.run @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:85(anonymous function) @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:451ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:225onInvokeTask @ VM2737 core.umd.js:6197ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:224Zone.runTask @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:125drainMicroTaskQueue @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:357ZoneTask.invoke @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:297
VM2737 core.umd.js:3009 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:ErrorHandler.handleError @ VM2737 core.umd.js:3009(anonymous function) @ VM2737 core.umd.js:6592ZoneDelegate.invoke @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:192onInvoke @ VM2737 core.umd.js:6206ZoneDelegate.invoke @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:191Zone.run @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:85(anonymous function) @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:451ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:225onInvokeTask @ VM2737 core.umd.js:6197ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:224Zone.runTask @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:125drainMicroTaskQueue @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:357ZoneTask.invoke @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:297
VM2737 core.umd.js:3010 TypeError: this.form._updateTreeValidity is not a function
    at FormGroupDirective._updateDomValue (VM2741 forms.umd.js:3643)
    at FormGroupDirective.ngOnChanges (VM2741 forms.umd.js:3569)
    at Wrapper_FormGroupDirective.detectChangesInInputProps (VM2791 wrapper.ngfactory.js:24)
    at _View_AddressComponent0.detectChangesInternal (VM2799 component.ngfactory.js:153)
    at _View_AddressComponent0.AppView.detectChanges (VM2737 core.umd.js:9305)
    at _View_AddressComponent0.DebugAppView.detectChanges (VM2737 core.umd.js:9410)
    at _View_AppComponent0.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (VM2737 core.umd.js:9331)
    at _View_AppComponent0.detectChangesInternal (VM2798 component.ngfactory.js:350)
    at _View_AppComponent0.AppView.detectChanges (VM2737 core.umd.js:9305)
    at _View_AppComponent0.DebugAppView.detectChanges (VM2737 core.umd.js:9410)ErrorHandler.handleError @ VM2737 core.umd.js:3010(anonymous function) @ VM2737 core.umd.js:6592ZoneDelegate.invoke @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:192onInvoke @ VM2737 core.umd.js:6206ZoneDelegate.invoke @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:191Zone.run @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:85(anonymous function) @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:451ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:225onInvokeTask @ VM2737 core.umd.js:6197ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:224Zone.runTask @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:125drainMicroTaskQueue @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:357ZoneTask.invoke @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:297
VM2737 core.umd.js:3013 ERROR CONTEXT:ErrorHandler.handleError @ VM2737 core.umd.js:3013(anonymous function) @ VM2737 core.umd.js:6592ZoneDelegate.invoke @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:192onInvoke @ VM2737 core.umd.js:6206ZoneDelegate.invoke @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:191Zone.run @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:85(anonymous function) @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:451ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:225onInvokeTask @ VM2737 core.umd.js:6197ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:224Zone.runTask @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:125drainMicroTaskQueue @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:357ZoneTask.invoke @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:297
VM2737 core.umd.js:3014 DebugContext {_view: _View_AddressComponent0, _nodeIndex: 0, _tplRow: 0, _tplCol: 5}ErrorHandler.handleError @ VM2737 core.umd.js:3014(anonymous function) @ VM2737 core.umd.js:6592ZoneDelegate.invoke @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:192onInvoke @ VM2737 core.umd.js:6206ZoneDelegate.invoke @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:191Zone.run @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:85(anonymous function) @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:451ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:225onInvokeTask @ VM2737 core.umd.js:6197ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:224Zone.runTask @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:125drainMicroTaskQueue @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:357ZoneTask.invoke @ VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:297
VM6060 zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser:344 Unhandled Promise rejection: Error in https://run.plnkr.co/8GpCKDyop2isKZyM/app/address.component.html:0:5 caused by: this.form._updateTreeValidity is not a function ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: ViewWrappedError {_nativeError: Error: Error in https://run.plnkr.co/8GpCKDyop2isKZyM/app/address.component.html:0:5 caused by: this…, originalError: TypeError: this.form._updateTreeValidity is not a function
    at FormGroupDirective._updateDomValue…, context: DebugContext} TypeError: this.form._updateTreeValidity is not a function
    at FormGroupDirective._updateDomValue (https://unpkg.com/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js:3643:23)
    at FormGroupDirective.ngOnChanges (https://unpkg.com/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js:3569:22)
    at Wrapper_FormGroupDirective.detectChangesInInputProps (/ReactiveFormsModule/FormGroupDirective/wrapper.ngfactory.js:24:18)
    at _View_AddressComponent0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/AddressComponent/component.ngfactory.js:153:32)
    at _View_AddressComponent0.AppView.detectChanges (https://unpkg.com/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9305:18)
    at _View_AddressComponent0.DebugAppView.detectChanges (https://unpkg.com/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9410:48)
    at _View_AppComponent0.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (https://unpkg.com/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9331:23)
    at _View_AppComponent0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/AppComponent/component.ngfactory.js:350:8)
    at _View_AppComponent0.AppView.detectChanges (https://unpkg.com/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9305:18)
```

`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is happening because you are passing invalid type to the `AddressComponent`

`AddressComponent` is expecting input with type `FormGroup`

**app/address.component.ts**

```
export class AddressComponent {
    @Input('group')
    public adressForm: FormGroup;
}
```

But you are passing `myForm.controls.addresses.controls` to `AddressComponent`, and it has incorrect type.

**app/app.component.html**

```
<div formArrayName="addresses">
    <address [group]="myForm.controls.addresses.controls"></address>
</div>
```

To fix that, you need to change your code to `myForm.controls.addresses`

**app/app.component.html**

```
<div formArrayName="addresses">
    <address [group]="myForm.controls.addresses"></address>
</div>
```

Working forked [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/7kFBGLkrETmEPv34Yafb?p=preview)